# nginx Virtual Host Problems

Tags: centos, nginx, virtualhost, centos7

I am running nginx on centos and using the method of having individual files for each domain inside a `sites-available` directory symlinked to `sites-enabled`.

Both conf files are almost identical.

My first virtual host worked fine but now I've added a second one, the non-`www` url redirects to `example.com` and the `www` url is not available.

i.e.

`example2.com -> example.com`

`www.example2.com -> not available`

**example.com**

```
# www to non-www redirect -- duplicate content is BAD:
# https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/5370479476dceae7cc3ea105946536d$
# Choose between www and non-www, listen on the *wrong* one and redirect to
# the right one -- http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Server_Name
server {
  # don't forget to tell on which port this server listens

  # commented out these two lines incase they were too general and resulting in this server being the first match for example2
  # listen [::]:80;
  # listen 80;

  # listen on the www host
  server_name www.example.com;

  # and redirect to the non-www host (declared below)
  return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  # listen 80 deferred; # for Linux
  # listen 80 accept_filter=httpready; # for FreeBSD

  # commented out these two lines incase they were too general and resulting in this server being the first match for example2
  # listen [::]:80;
  # listen 80;

  # The host name to respond to
  server_name www.example.com;

  # Path for static files
  root /var/www/example.com/public_html/;
  index index.html index.php

  # Specify a charset
  charset utf-8;

  # Custom 404 page
  error_page 404 /404.html;


  location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      # fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include        fastcgi_params;
  }

}
```

**example2.com**

```
# www to non-www redirect -- duplicate content is BAD:
# https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/5370479476dceae7cc3ea105946536d$
# Choose between www and non-www, listen on the *wrong* one and redirect to
# the right one -- http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Server_Name
server {
  # don't forget to tell on which port this server listens
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 80;

  # listen on the www host
  server_name example2.com;

  # and redirect to the non-www host (declared below)
  return 301 $scheme://example2.com$request_uri;
} 

server {
  # listen 80 deferred; # for Linux
  # listen 80 accept_filter=httpready; # for FreeBSD
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 80;

  # The host name to respond to
  server_name example2.com;

  # Path for static files
  root /var/www/example2.com/public_html/;
   index index.html index.php

  # Specify a charset
  charset utf-8;

  # Custom 404 page
  error_page 404 /404.html;


  location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      # fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include        fastcgi_params;
  }

}
```

Browser message for `www.example2.com`

`The server at www.fionacreative.co.uk can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.`

I did change the name servers this morning but they seem to be updated with the domain registrar.

I don't think this explains `http://example2.com` resolving to `example.com` though, both should be the same.

Comment: What does *"www path is not available"* mean?

Comment: @Sven, I try and make that clearly in the lines underneath. I basically mean that `www.example2.com` gets a not available message in the browser whilst the non-www `example2.com` just redirects to `example.com`, hopefully that makes sense now, I will try and edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Tell us at least what exact error message you get, both in the browser and the log files. It's kind of hard to diagnose the problem if you don't tell us the whole story and then insert additional issues when editing your config files...

Comment: What does `www.example2.com -> not available` actually mean (the output of `curl -I http://www.example2.com` would clarify)? Sounds likely to be dns, and not nginx config related.

Comment: A thought: Are your DNS entries in order and pointing to the correct host?

Comment: @AD7six `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.fionacreative.co.uk; Name or service not known`. I just changed the name servers this morning. Any ideas on the non-www url resolving to `example.com` though? The message in the browser is `This webpage is not available`, will update question with full message.

Comment: which indicates your question has zero to do with nginx @martincarlin87 - as such anything in the question about nginx, OS, anything-on-the-server-at-all is irrelevant.

Comment: @martincarlin87: Please learn to ask good questions involving correct code and all relevant details. This is just a waste of time :(

Comment: @Sven - updated the question. I updated the nameservers this morning with the registrar but they have updated on there and should be pointing to the new server's nameservers. I like to think I ask good questions (I am more active on SO as I am a developer and not a sysadmin but I've just set up a droplet on Digital Ocean and trying to configure everything before moving all of my existing sites to it).

Comment: Honestly: As a sysadmin question, this sucked. And this is why we are very wary when we see a user with a high SO rep and no SF rep :(  Please read http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault and the [help].

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Your problem is your DNS configuration, `nginx` isn't involved.

There is no host defintion for `www.fionacreative.co.uk`, but there is one for `fionacreative.co.uk`.

---

**Original based on malformed question**

You have `example2.com` defined twice, you need to add `www` to  one of the server names to work, likely the first definition.

```
server {
  # don't forget to tell on which port this server listens
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 80;

  # listen on the www host
  #############################
  server_name www.example2.com;         ##### this line needs a www ######
  #############################

  # and redirect to the non-www host (declared below)
  return 301 $scheme://example2.com$request_uri;
} 

server {
  # listen 80 deferred; # for Linux
  # listen 80 accept_filter=httpready; # for FreeBSD
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 80;

  # The host name to respond to
  server_name example2.com;
```

Comment: sorry @Sven, the missing `www` was a typo when I was replacing the actual domain name I'm using, just updated the question. I should've noticed the mistake when making the updates to post on here.

Comment: I was talking about the definition of `example2.com`. Is this the same issue of you not being careful while posting? Also, now your first domain `example.com` wouldn't work, as both are defined as `www.example.com` now, and `example.com` is missing....

Comment: yes, it's the same, it's there in my actual conf for `example2.com` but I erased the `www` when replacing the actual domain with `example2`. I have one `www` and one `non-www` definition in each conf.

Answer (score -1):

I was downvoted to oblivion but I managed to solve my issue.

Everyone else was right, this wasn't an error to do with nginx, it was a DNS issue but I'm not used to nginx and trying it out instead of apache this time which didn't help matters.

Anyway, turns out although I had an A Name record for `example2.com` I needed another for `www.example2.com`, then give it a few minutes to propagate, clear your cache and it should work.